# Not getting count of different string - MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one query as given below,

```
select device_id,CAST(device_dtt_st as date),count(*) as g,'' as s,'' as m
from  event_data_170309
where device_id ='8D-15-DB'and raw_data like %GPRS%'
group by CAST(device_dtt_st as date)
union
select device_id,CAST(device_dtt_st as date),'' as g,count(*) as s,'' as m
from  event_data_170309
where device_id ='8D-15-DB' and raw_data like '%SMS%'
group by CAST(device_dtt_st as date)
union
select device_id,CAST(device_dtt_st as date),'' as g,'' as s,count(*) as m
from  event_data_170309
where device_id ='8D-15-DB'and !(raw_data like '%SMS%' or raw_data like '%GPRS%')
group by CAST(device_dtt_st as date);
```

and I got output as in two different row, but I want count in only one row.

[image]

see the below scenario,
[image]

Comment: Im sorry. I dont understand the question, you only want the count of a query?

Comment: No I have one column as long string which is having character like 'GPRS', 'SMS' etc. I want the count by that character in one row

Comment: thanks @David Makogon i was not able to format the query here

Comment: @Annu - Please edit your question to show desired results and current results. (also, please use proper formatting when doing so)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Union will return multiple rows only.**

You will need to wrap all these queries with another query and then count it.
ex.

```
select count(param), sum(param), param
from 
    (
        select param as param, count(param)
        union
        another query with same column output
        union 
        yet another query with same column output
    ) as childQuery
group by childQuery.param
```

*EDIT*
Added a aggregated function, whichever you want to use.

*EDIT2*

```
SELECT 
   DEVICE_ID, 
   DATE,
   SUM(IF(DATA LIKE %SMS%,1,0)) AS TOTAL_SMS,
   SUM(IF(DATA LIKE %GPRS%,1,0)) AS TOTAL_GPRS,
   SUM(IF(DATA NOT LIKE %GPRS% AND DATA NOT LIKE %SMS%,1,0)) AS TOTAL_OTHER,
FROM 
   YOUR_TABLE T
GROUP BY
   T.DATE
```

ABove query will work for your desired output

Comment: thanks for the help but still not getting desired output

Comment: Can you add desired output here

Comment: @Annu what out put you get ?

Comment: please see the newly attached image

Comment: Thank you soo much for the answer, i got it.